# How to get the value of a String from other class to a class in Android?

Tags: java, android, constructor

my code goes like this, a created a constructor. and i want to access the string from homepage.java to login.php. but android gives me an error "access to constructor not allowed".. am i doing it wrong? pls help.
HomePage.java

```
public class HomePage extends Activity {

private Button clBtn;
private Button bcBtn;
private Button atBtn;
public String ip="";

 HomePage()
 {
    this.ip = "http://111.111.11.1/sp/";
 }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_page);
    }
}
```

login.java

```
public class Login extends Activity {

private EditText etFacNo; 
private EditText etPassword;
private Button loginBtn;
HomePage getIP = new HomePage();
String url = getIP.ip;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_page);

    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url+"loginteacher.php");

}
}
```

Comment: Are your `Login` class and `HomePage` class in the same package?

Comment: use public in HomePage constructor

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

You've declared the constructor for `HomePage` with *no modifier*. This means that only classes in the same package can call it which is why you're getting that error.

```
HomePage()
{
    ...
```

Make it `public`

```
public HomePage()
{
    ...
```